# Appium + native device error

Tags: appium

i am try to run first script of appium to check the set up installed properly, but facing exception please help.

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ERROR running Appium command: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\build-tools' Command duration or timeout: 171 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40' System info: host: 'LAPTOP-FHNL3FTF', ip: '192.168.1.180', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if you have the android build tools and if it is correctly added to your path, which is what the exception stack is complaining about?

It is looking for the build tools in your 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\build-tools', check path env variable, and also check if that env variable that points to the build tools folder corresponding to the api level number (e.g. 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\build-tools\22.0'.